# Help me figure out these Handwriting English

Tags: handwriting

I wrote a paper. A German professor gave me some handwriting comments about it. But it's hard for me to figure some words out since I am not a native English speaker. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid we're not a service for deciphering handwriting .

Comment: Dear god. Good luck with that. In the meantime, see whether your prof has ever thought about going into medicine...

Comment: One thing that might help can be deduced from the first two words "general comment" which shows how the Prof writes the **g** and omits crossing the **t**, and the (almost) whole sentence says "general comment: the method is rather comprehensive - it might be better to subdivide in steps xxxx." The sentence marked '2' says "maybe this item is a bit short to refer to the whole?" The last section starts with "Machine learning."

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you for this helpful comment, upvote for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try, "General comment: The method is rather comprehensive; may be better to subdivide in step 1, step 2....

Later, an, enhancing

'the' has been inserted in two places.

Why here time  t      but before s   ?
To explain (or to change?)
2) May be this....a bit short to refer to the whole?
...further...
Machine learning meet editor Yang Tang
Reviewers

Comment: I think it's **item** in 2.

Comment: Image 4 also has 'may be this xxxx (ARM) is a bit short to refer to the whole?'

Comment: Great job. Thank you all so very much. I think my problem is well solved by all of you.

Comment: Don’t try. Read what this site is about and only answer questions that fit with its aims and are worth answering.

Comment: @guorui — Your question has been declared off-topic, as must have been evident from the description of the purpose of this site in the Tour. Such obviously off-topic questions are an abuse of the site, and answers only encourage posters and others to continue such abuse.